# Expected value with symbolic probabilities in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, probability

I'd like to find the expected value of a discrete random variable without specifying a particular distribution so I can still manipulate the entire expression symbolically.

For example, how would I get the rhs of the following expectation using summation in sympy?

http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21%5Csum_%7Bi%20%3D%201%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20P%28a_i%29a_i%20%3D%20P%28a_1%29a_1%20%2B%20...%20%2B%20P%28a_n%29a_n%20.gif

Comment: Why don't you just multiply and add up the values/probabilities?

Comment: Are you using sympy.stats?  If so then be advised that we don't go *this* symbolic in our manipulations.  You need to specify a distribution.  Raise an issue if this is important for you.  However if you're fine using just straight sympy symbols though then see @asmeurer's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `n` is unknown, you can use `summation`

```
In [45]: i, n = symbols('i n', integer=True)

In [46]: p, a = symbols('p a', cls=Function)

In [47]: summation(p(a(i))*a(i), (i, 0, n))
Out[47]:
  n
 ___
 ╲
  ╲   a(i)⋅p(a(i))
  ╱
 ╱
 ‾‾‾
i = 0
```

If `n` is known, you'll probably want to just represent the actual sum:

```
In [48]: n = 10

In [49]: sum(p(a(i))*a(i) for i in range(1, n+1))
Out[49]: a(1)⋅p(a(1)) + a(2)⋅p(a(2)) + a(3)⋅p(a(3)) + a(4)⋅p(a(4)) + a(5)⋅p(a(5)) + a(6)⋅p(a(6)) + a(7)⋅p(a(7)) + a(8)⋅p(a(8)) + a(9)⋅p(a(9)) + a(10)⋅p(a(10))
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't thought about indexing by using functions, that's a nice solution.